# Moment of inertia of a cube along one of its diagonal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Yes I've seen the other question posted on the site - [Moment of inertia of solid cube about body diagonal](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222905/moment-of-inertia-of-solid-cube-about-body-diagonal?rq=1) , but I don't really understand the solution

The final result is $m l^2/6$, but I'm not able to get it.

I assumed it would be the same as the moment of inertia of diagonal for a square but that's $ml^2/12$.

When we rotate both of them along the axis we will get the same shape won't we?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For calculation of moment of inertia, what actually matters is the mass distribution and not the shape the body makes while rotating. When a square is kept along its diagonal then we get the shape of two isosceles triangle about the axis. But when cube is kept about its diagonal, the shape is of a pyramid about the axis. These shapes are different and hence mass distribution about them is different. So your assumption :

```
I assumed it would be the same as the moment of inertia of diagonal for a square
 but that's 2/12.

When we rotate both of them along the axis we will get the same shape won't we?
```

is fundamentally wrong.

Note that law for moment inertia does not take into consideration how the body is rotating.

$$I={\int r^2 dm}$$

---

**To solve:**

Divide the pyramid into squares with infinitesimal small depth and find their moment of inertia $dI$ using Parallel Axis Theorem in a coordinate system. Integrate them to get your answer.

Comment: right ! now how do I move on after this ? how to I find it for the cube?

Comment: @JustJohan I have given a hint in  my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> When we rotate both of them along the axis we will get the same shape won't we?

No. Cut a square in half along a diagonal so that you have two isosceles right angled triangles. The three dimensional shape that you get when you rotate one of these triangles about its axis of symmetry is a cone. So the three dimensional shape that you get when you rotate a square about a diagonal is two back-to-back cones joined at their base, which is called a [bicone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicone). It is not a cube.

Comment: instead of rotating about the axis of symmetry  and rotate along the hypotenuse wont we get the same shape?

Comment: @JustJohan Yes, it is the same shape - two cones joined at their base, also known as a bicone. Not a cube.

Comment: I think @JustJohan is asking whether rotating a cube about its long diagonal also yields a bicone.  The answer to that is also no, though I'm not quite sure how to describe the shape.  [Here it is](https://imgur.com/a/OPzl0td) (technically 100 cubes superimposed, but it gives a good sense of it.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert yep thanks, now I am back to square one again.  :(